# Newton Raphson Step Size

Tags: numerical-methods

I am solving old exams and I came across the following question:

> Let 
>   $$
> x_{n+1} = x_{n} - \alpha\frac{f(x_{n})}{f'(x_{n})}  \;\;,\;\; f(x_{n}) \gt0  \;\;,\;\; f'(x_{n}) \neq0
> $$
>   Is it true that there exists an $0 \lt \alpha \lt 1$ such that $f(x_{n+1}) \lt f(x_{n})$ for all $n$?

I vaguely remember we discussed this in class and the answer was (to my surprise) "yes", but I didn't understand the reason and didn't write the explanation down.

Can you point me in the right direction?

Thanks! :)

Comment: Check whether $f(x_{n+1}) < f(x_n)$ near $\alpha \to 0+$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's expand $f(x_{n+1})$ using Taylor formula with Lagrange remainder term:
$$
f(x_{n+1}) = f\left(x_n - \alpha \frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}\right) = 
f(x_n) - \alpha f'(x_n) \frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)} + f''(\xi) \frac{\alpha^2 f^2(x_n)}{2(f'(x_n))^2} = \\ =(1 - \alpha) f(x_n)
+ \frac{\alpha^2}{2}\frac{f^2(x_n)}{(f'(x_n))^2}f''(\xi) \leqslant
(1 - \alpha) f(x_n)
+ \frac{\alpha^2}{2}\frac{f^2(x_n)}{(f'(x_n))^2}M_2
$$
where $M_2 = \max\limits_{\xi \in [a,b]} |f''(\xi)|$.
Thus
$$
q \equiv \frac{f(x_{n+1})}{f(x_n)} \leqslant 1 - \alpha + \frac{\alpha^2}{2}
\frac{f(x_n)}{(f'(x_n))^2} M_2
$$
I state that exists some $\alpha$ that for every $x_n$ the value of $q \in (0, 1)$:
$$
\left|q - 1 + \alpha\right| \leqslant \frac{\alpha^2}{2} \frac{f(x_n)}{(f'(x_n))^2} M_2 \leqslant \frac{\alpha^2}{2} \frac{M_0 M_2}{m_1^2}
$$
where $m_1 = \max\limits_{\xi \in [a,b]} |f'(\xi)|$ and $M_0 = \max\limits_{\xi \in [a,b]} |f(\xi)|$. Let $\beta \equiv \frac{M_0M_2}{m_1^2}$. Then
$$
\left|q - 1 + \alpha\right| \leqslant \frac{\beta \alpha^2}{2}.
$$
By taking sufficiently small $\alpha$ we can ensure that $q$ stays in interval $(0,1)$. The actual value for $\alpha$ can be $\alpha = \frac{1}{\beta}$ for $\beta \geqslant 2$ and $\alpha = \frac{1}{2}$ for $\beta < 2$.

Note that uniform value for $\alpha$ depends on uniform estimates for derivatives taken over some domain containing all points $x_n$.

Comment: So it means that I need to choose a new $\alpha$ for each $n$, right? (because as $f(x_n) \rightarrow 0$, $\alpha f(x_n)$ becomes $O(\alpha^2)$ as well)

Comment: @Hila Yes, that proof picks up an $\alpha$ for each $n$. I'll update it

Answer (score 2):

*Hinit*: What you meant is called [halley method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halley%27s_method) such that the Algorithm can be written as follow :$$ x_{n+1} = x_{n} - \frac{f(x_{n})}{f'(x_{n})}[1-\frac{f(x_{n})}{f'(x_{n})}\frac{f''(x_{n})}{2f'(x_{n})}]^{-1}$$

Also you can check [this](http://www.sztaki.hu/~bozoki/oktatas/nemlinearis/SebahGourdon-Newton.pdf) pdf page 5 (4.2 Householder’s iteration) may help

you to understand well your modified Algorithm .